# JavaScript list items are inconsistent after being pushed to database

Tags: javascript, ajax, database

I'm trying to set up an ajax end point on my server that creates a new transaction object and add it to a block, and the block is added to a local blockchain.

The issue is that it works fine without calling my database function add_block, which adds the new block to the database. But after adding the add_block call, any new blocks I create with the ajax function becomes empty, as opposed to having a transaction. The odd thing is that the block is not empty and is correctly added to the database.

The add_block function returns a promise after the block is added to the database.

I printed out the blockchain before and after the add_block function call. Before the call the new block will be properly displayed with the new transaction in it. But after the call the new block will be displayed but with no transactions in it at all. And any future ajax calls will also display empty blocks instead.

---This is the ajax function running on a node server---

```
app.post("/transact", function(request, response) {

    let sendAddress = jerryWalletAddress;
    let getAddress = benWalletAddress;
    let amount = 5;

    let thisTransaction = new Transaction(sendAddress, getAddress, amount);
    // adds the transaction to a pending list
    testChain.addTransaction(thisTransaction);

    // creates a block object holding all transactions in the pending list
    testChain.minePendingTransactions(jerryWalletAddress);

    // This will print the correct output    
    testChain.printChain();

    // This is the db function that adds the block to a db
    blockchainDB.add_block(testChain.chain[testChain.chain.length-1]).then(()=> {
        // This will print the incorrect output
        testChain.printChain();
    });
});
```

Assuming there are 2 valid transactions before the ajax call:

The correct list when printChain() is called is something like:

Block 1

-Transaction 1

Block 2

-Transaction 1

Block 3

-Transaction 1

The incorrect list when `printChain()` is called a second time is something like:

Block 1

-Transaction 1

Block 2

-Transaction 2

Block 3

Block 4

Block 5

Comment: Give me the add_block code

Answer (score 0):

So apparently my add_block function is actually popping the transaction from the transaction array in the block when adding to db.

It helped a lot for me to use the VSCode's debugger to run through my node code to see exactly where it went wrong.

Comment: You may want to delete this question, as there is no way anyone else could have deduced this answer without the code for `add_block`.